# How can I use Google Analytics to find 404 pages?

Tags: google-analytics, 404

I am trying to use Google Analytics to find `404` pages using the following set of instructions:

> To begin, go to Google Analytics and then navigate to *Customization »
> Custom Reports*. Now click on + New Custom Report.
>
> Next, you’ll have to give a name to your report, like Broken Links
> Report. And then enter the following settings:
>
> - Change the Type to Flat Table
> - For Dimensions, add Landing Page and    then Full Referrer
> - For Metrics, search and add Entrances
> - Then in the Filters, click add filter and select Page Title (make sure the first    dropdown is set to Include and the next is set to
>   Exact)
> - Enter the exact title of your broken link, such as Page not found or 404.html
> - Select All views associated with this account under Views
> - Click Save when you’re done

[Source](https://www.monsterinsights.com/how-to-find-broken-links-with-google-analytics/)

However, the report is always empty (there is no data for this view) for whatever time range, though I know there were some `404` pages during this period.

Can you tell me what might be wrong with this method or how else I can accomplish this?

I also checked [Using analytics to find what pages brought users to a 404](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87117/using-analytics-to-find-what-pages-brought-users-to-a-404) and it seems that the OP is using a similar method to find `404` pages.

Update

My site uses WP Rocket and I check the 404 page and find the following code:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxx-xxx"></script>
<script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx-xxx');
        gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxx');
      </script>
```

Not sure if that will affect the Google Analysics report.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the analytics snippet is installed on your 404 template?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, The analytics snippet is included. But I am using WP Rocket and it will delay execute the analytics script, not sure whether that will affect the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to "Behavior" and "Content" you can filter for 404 in the title or URL. Once you have that page you can save it as a report and have it emailed every day, week, or month.

Comment: Thank you very much. With your method, I am able to see the 404 pages.